# Как лучше всего создавать глобальный объект?

Tags: javascript

Как лучше всего создавать глобальный объект? Если в объекте создается переменная для которой нужен загруженный DOM
Если DOM загруженный не нужен, то можно так

```
photoFunc = {
     obj_size: 'eclipse'
  }
```

А если нужен то так ?

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    photoEl()

}, false);

function photoEl(){
  return  photoFunc = {
     obj_size: document.getElementById('eclipse')
  }
}
```

Comment: ретурн в обработчики события - это канечно круто, но бесполезно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глобальный объект создаётся так: window.globalObject = {}

Comment: разве только так?

1. 
        var globalObject = "globalObject";
        window.globalObject // globalObject

2.
        (function(){ 
            this.globalObject = "globalObject";
        }());
        window.globalObject // globalObject

3.
        ...

Comment: так мне надо, его, сделать глобальным после загруpки DOM

Comment: @Zow, вы меня уже который раз удивляете неумением самостоятельно решить даже самую элементарную задачу